# How do I efficiently redistribute massive amounts of data spread across multiple drives with almost no space on them?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems, defragment

My problem is simple but severe. I have a huge amount of data (many files in many folders) on multiple drives (4 external HDD). Each drive is at least 1TB in size and the overall size of this "pool" is > 7TB. No drive has more than a few GB free. The largest file is 20Gb and most files are around 500MB to 2GB.

I want to reorganize the files on all of the drives. The problem is that I can't simple move one folder from one drive to another drive because the space left on each of these drives is so low that this would never work. Doing everything by hand is not imaginable and would take forever.

I am looking for a tool (free or paid) that allows me to do the following things:

- change / reorganize the file structure of multiple drives BEFORE actually moving / copying any data; so I want to virtually rearrange the drives before actually doing it
- reorganizing shall include redistribution across all drives; i.e. file A may go from drive X to drive Y and file B may go from drive Y to drive X and so on...
- the tool that I am looking for shall be able to calculate the resulting actual free space for any included drive before actually moving anything so that I can see how to rearrange stuff so that it really fits on the drives
- when everything has been virtually reorganized I want this tool to calculate the "shortest" most efficient way to actually reorganize everything
- finally when the perfect reorganizing procedure has been calculated the tool shall actually perform the file movements - taking into account the space left on each drive at every moment during this process!

Such a tool takes away the burden of not being able to restructure my drives - and also everything would go the most efficient way.

So one could say that what I am looking for is some sort of defragmentation for files cluttered across several disks!

Is there any such tool available to do the job? Preferably it shall be an open source tool.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Buy a 6TB drive. Clone one drive to it. Now you have room to play.

Comment: Sorry, Sir, at the moment I simply cannot afford another HD. The memory left on all of these drives is roughly 70GB - so the overall space is enough to keep everything - however I need to redistribute the data in order to sort it in a better way.